# in Xcode12 beta the Swift package manager fails to load dependencies

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

Recently the SPM has started to give me errors. Was working before.
I'm trying to use the AlamofireImage library but xcode fails to resolve de dependency and doesn't give any good explanation.
Does anybody know why and how to make it work?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this was once happened to me, maybe you can try to go ahead to File > Swift Packages > Update to Latest Package Versions. Let's see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I was trying to arrange the files inside the project folder, and when I put them back to their old position the problem was resolved and the app run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that's not ideal, but works for now. In your main xCode project file, go under Project not Target and find Package Dependencies. After finding it, remove the SDK, and then right click on the name of your project and add a package. This time when adding Firebase, use Minor version. It should hopefully resolve and install.